# SSIS - Delete and Insert All Rows or Update and Insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, data-warehouse

I'm trying to find out what is the best way to do it.

Having a view on the live data and I want to insert the rows to my DW table. Not sure what will be more efficient.

- Delete all rows from destination table and insert the entire view.
- Only update or insert new rows.

**It takes 4 mins to delete the rows and insert the entire view. Trying to see if update and insert only new will make it faster.**

Right now I have 350k rows in my live DB and it increasing 2000/week. The view/table has 90 columns and I'm not sure how to do it in SSIS.

- Should I do a join between the view and destination table?
- Should I use lookup and insert new row? (Does that work in case of
  update    needed?)

I looked at couple of examples online, but not sure if I need to do the join on all columns in order to check for updated rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to consider - 
1. Is there any need to maintain the history? If yes, then you cannot truncate and reload.

1. Growth rate: 2000 (Rows/week) * 52 (weeks/year) = 104,000 (Rows/year)
   So, in 3 years, it will double (roughly). It does - not - mean that it would start taking 8 mins. It may take say 5-6 mins. With the inset/update technique, even if you save say 2 mins per run, is that critical? If not, then why introduce complexity to the process.
2. If you need a quantitative comparison of the two methods, you would need write the code and compare - I do not know any short cut.
3. IF you decide to do insert/update, I would suggest you to keep a hash of all 90 columns in a new column. While doing the merge, compare the hash, and if different, update all 90 columns. Ninety columns are way to many to compare individually.

If need further help with insert/update with hash-comparison, please revert back.

Comment: This is what I thought. Much better just to delete and insert the entire view. Just wanted to confirm the general idea here.

Comment: what do you recommend to do if I want to append the entire table every week. so insert the entire view to the same table every week. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: What is the use case for your proposition? For example, if none of the rows change, you would end up with duplicate records being stored. Is this what you really want? Unless there is a strong use case for this, I would stay away from this approach. If you describe your purpose, we can offer a solution without requiring to store duplicates. A simple and standard way is to have these three fields:1. DateCreated 2. DateUpdated 3. IsCurrent (Yes, this is kind of redundant, but helpful)

Comment: we want to keep history. I want to check how were sales last year in week 30. If I keep update rows, clients can cancel booking and the calculation will not be correct.